Need help including header files in CMake
I'm relatively new using CMake and I have a problem that I don't know how to fix.
First of all, the context. My project structure is this:
├── project/  
│   ├── bin/  
│   ├── framework/  
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt  
│   │   ├── include/  
│   │   └── src/  
│   ├── engine/  
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt  
│   │   ├── include/  
│   │   └── src/  
│   ├── core/  
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt  
│   │   ├── include/  
│   │   └── src/  
│   ├── vendor/  
│   └── CMakeLists.txt  
│   └── main.cpp  
│   └── commands.h  
│   └── commands.cpp

project/framework/CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.31.0)
project(FrameworkLib)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -std=c++17 -Wall")

file(GLOB_RECURSE FRAMEWORK_SOURCES src/*.cpp)
add_library(FrameworkLib STATIC ${FRAMEWORK_SOURCES})

target_include_directories(FrameworkLib PUBLIC
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)

target_link_libraries(FrameworkLib PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2 SDL2_image SDL2_mixer SDL2_net SDL2_ttf)

project/engine/CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.31.0)
project(EngineLib)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -std=c++17 -Wall")

file(GLOB_RECURSE ENGINE_SOURCES src/*.cpp)
add_library(EngineLib STATIC ${ENGINE_SOURCES})

target_include_directories(EngineLib PUBLIC
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../framework
)

target_link_libraries(EngineLib PRIVATE FrameworkLib SDL2::SDL2 SDL2_image SDL2_mixer SDL2_net SDL2_ttf)

project/core/CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.31.0) \ project(CoreLib)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -std=c++17 -Wall")

file(GLOB_RECURSE CORE_SOURCES src/*.cpp)
add_library(CoreLib STATIC ${CORE_SOURCES})

target_include_directories(CoreLib PUBLIC
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../framework \ ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../engine \ )

target_link_libraries(CoreLib PRIVATE FrameworkLib EngineLib SDL2::SDL2 SDL2_image SDL2_mixer SDL2_net SDL2_ttf)

project/CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.31.0)

project(Arkwright)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -std=c++20 -Wall")

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

set(FETCHCONTENT_BASE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor)
include(FetchContent)

# SDL2
FetchContent_Declare(
SDL2
URL https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.30.9.tar.gz
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SDL2)

# SDL2_image
FetchContent_Declare(
SDL2_image
URL https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.8.2.tar.gz
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SDL2_image)

# SDL2_mixer
FetchContent_Declare(
SDL2_mixer
URL https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-2.8.0.tar.gz
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SDL2_mixer)

# SDL2_net
FetchContent_Declare(
SDL2_net
URL https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_net/release/SDL2_net-2.2.0.tar.gz
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SDL2_net)

# SDL2_ttf
FetchContent_Declare(
SDL2_ttf
URL https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-2.22.0.tar.gz
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SDL2_ttf)

add_subdirectory(core)
add_subdirectory(framework)
add_subdirectory(engine)

file(GLOB_RECURSE MAIN_SOURCES core/src/*.cpp)

add_executable(Arkwright ${MAIN_SOURCES})

target_include_directories(Arkwright PRIVATE
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/framework/include
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/engine/include
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/core/include
)

target_link_libraries(Arkwright PRIVATE EngineLib SDL2::SDL2 SDL2_image SDL2_mixer SDL2_net SDL2_ttf)

Well, when I enter cmake .. (being into the bin folder), it works correctly. But when I enter cmake --build . it throws me that error:
In file included from /home/yawin/Dokumentuak/Proyectos/Gamedev/Arkwright/src/engine/include/actor.h:27,
from /home/yawin/Dokumentuak/Proyectos/Gamedev/Arkwright/src/engine/src/actor.cpp:22:
/home/yawin/Dokumentuak/Proyectos/Gamedev/Arkwright/src/engine/include/sprite.h:27:10: fatal error: framework/rf_process.h: No existe el fichero o el directorio
27 | #include "framework/rf_process.h"

I think the problem is because I'm including it as framework/file.h and, given the way I've included the directory folders, I should just put file.h. But, for clarity, I'd like the framework headers to be included as framework/file.h, the engine headers as engine/file.h and the core headers as core/file.h.
On the other hand, I get the feeling that even though SDL2 and its modules are downloaded, when I do #include <SDL2/SDL.h> it's including the headers I have installed on the system. But this is just something I think, I haven't been able to verify it.
What do I have to change for it to work?

If you want to be able to include files like that, you need to have a directory structure like that.
